# Moving Woocommerce Order Review to Top of Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to move the order review section to the top of Woocommerce checkout page and this is working:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review',    'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );
```

But when Checkout opens it scrolls down to the order review section, rather than to the top of the page.

Comment: This does move the order review to the top of the checkotu page. but it seems the jquery for choosing shipping method is no longer working. for example, the shipping prices doesn't get updated anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'woocommerce_order_review', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the review form doesn't automatically move the `Your Order` heading. This is what I added to functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'prefix_wc_order_review_heading', 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_order_review', 4 );

/**
 * Add a heading for order review on checkout page. 
 * This replaces the heading added by WooCommerce since order review is moved to the top of the checkout page.
 */
function prefix_wc_order_review_heading() {
    echo '<h3>Your Order</h3>';
}
```

And to hide the existing `Your Order` heading (and some spacing for the credit card form), I added this to style.css

```
.woocommerce-checkout #order_review_heading {
    display: none !important;
}

.woocommerce-checkout #order_review {
    margin-top: 2rem !important;
}
```